# How do I report vulnerability in sudo?

Tags: sudo, vulnerability

I have found a vulnerability in sudo and I was able to reproduce it on multiple instances of xubuntu. It didn't seem to work on debian.

How do I report it properly?
I have read so much about responsible disclosure, but noone says where to look for information...

Comment: Are you certain the bug is in sudo, and not the xubuntu specific configuration?  Try using your Debian config on Xubuntu.

Comment: You can find a software vulnerability but have to ask how to report it to the maintainer?

Comment: @AaronCopley That's right. It's the first time I found a vuln that I wasn't able to google. My belief in `stack.*` community made me think it's a good idea to ask before deciding what to do. And I was encouraged to choose an option that wasn't my first choice. (I didn't know launchpad bugs can be private; why would I?) Are you trying to discourage that kind of behaviour?

Comment: @Zoredache You're right that it's ubuntu-specific. But I used the same config on both systems. It's about something lower-level than sudoers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://xubuntu.org/contribute/qa/) describes how to file a bug in Xubuntu. What is not said is that during the process you will be redirected to Launchpad where you will be able to mark the bug as a security vulnerability, see screenshot below:

[image: This bug is a security vulnerability]

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), you can find the sudo homepage [here](http://www.sudo.ws/)

There seems to be a mailing list for maintainers [here](http://www.sudo.ws/mailman/listinfo/sudo-workers)

For ubuntu specific bugs you can use security@ubuntu.com

Comment: ok, but it looks like it's ubuntu specific. does this change anything?

Comment: For ubuntu you can use security@ubuntu.com. By the way, the only thing I did was roughly rephrase your question into Google's search box...

Comment: I know I look really lame asking about that, but when I googled there was a lot of results saying different things... I wanted to ask people who did stuff like that already. Maybe I should have gone to security stackexchange. my bad.